# xinetdでポートフォワーディングした後、nginxで実体IPを受け取りたい

Tags: nginx

こんにちは。

私は、sudoしていないnginxでport 80を受け付けるため、xinetdでポートフォワーディングを行っています。

```
service nginx
{
  disable = no
  type = UNLISTED
  socket_type = stream
  protocol = tcp
  wait = no
  user = root
  port = 80
  redirect = 127.0.0.1 8000
  log_type = FILE /var/log/xinetdlog
}
```

xinetd.d 内の設定は以上のように行いました。
この設定で、ポートフォワーディング 80->8000 はうまく成されました。

しかし、8000で受け取っているnginx側のlogのアクセス元IPがすべて127.0.0.1となってしまいます。
これを、実体IP(xinetdのport 80にアクセスしてきたユーザーのIP)にしたいと考えています。

nginx.confにおける $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for にX-Forwarded-ForのIPが記録されているのではないかと期待しましたが、nginx側のlog formatに指定したところ、中身は127.0.0.1となっていました。

XinetdにはX-Forwarded-Forを出力する機構は備わっていないのでしょうか？

Comment: この場合、 `xinetd` がプロキシになっているので、簡単には `nginx` から直接外の IP を見ることはできなさそうです。 `iptables` を使うべきかな。

Comment: xinetd から X-Forwarded-For を受け取ることはできないでしょうか？

Comment: [xinetd redirect.c](https://github.com/xinetd-org/xinetd/blob/master/xinetd/redirect.c) を見ますと、単なるブリッジにしかなっていない様ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。わかりました、iptablesなどを使う事にします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xinetd` を通して redirect した場合、redirect 先のプロセスは接続元の IP を直接知ることはできません。透過的に接続させたい場合は、`xinetd` を使わず `iptables` 使用するのが良いでしょう。 `X-Forwarded-For` ヘッダを付加するなどして、 HTTP プロトコルの範囲でクライアント IP を知らせたければ、最低リバースプロキシを用意する必要があります。

プロキシを使用したいとなれば、 nginx が軽くてよいです。別ポートを受付にして、以下のように [`proxy_pass` ディレクティブ](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)付きで立ち上げる設定をします。

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy-80-to-8000.conf

server {
    listen       80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Client-IP     $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

ローカルの別ポートを向いたプロキシとして nginx を使うとなると、根本的なこととして「なぜ HTTP サーバ側があらかじめポート 80 を開けていないのか」という疑問が発生しますが、アクセスログが分けられますし、[ロードバランシング](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)用途に簡単に切り替えられるので、その辺で意味があるのかなと思います。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。ありがとうございます。